# mysql asp.net c# unicode

Tags: asp.net, mysql, utf-8

I'm crazy about getting the content from mysql db and display it in vietnamese but always get strange code.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    string myConnectionString = 
        "Database=abc;Data Source=x.x.x.;User Id=abc;Password=abc;charset=utf8";

    MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);

    MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(
        "SELECT location_name FROM idv_province", myConnection);
    MySqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(myCommand);

    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
    myAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "idv_province");

    foreach (DataRow row in myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
          lblProvince.Text += row["location_name"].ToString() + "<br/>";
    }
}
```

my page already has

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

it's been driving me crazy for a whole day. please help me, thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the meta tag for UTF-8 does not necessarily "convert" your ASPX page to UTF-8.

You also have to save the ASPX file in Visual Studio as UTF-8. See `File` > `Advanced Save Options...`.

In addition, if you haven't read it, I would recommend reading [Joel's introduction to Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: thanks for your info but i think there's some problem on mysql/.net connector(latest version) itself. Somehow, i cannot interpret the correct code though on the same connection, same database server, php can read it properly